# How to make objects float on water in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, game-physics, vertices

I've been working on a game for the team seas game jam, and I'm trying to make a boat that will actually float, I've but ran into a issue, so to explain it the way the current script works is it checks for the position of some point on the boat and if the points are below the y level of the plane/water then it will add an upward force to that point. Here's that code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Floater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float depthBeforeSubmerged = 1f;
    public float displacementAmount = 3f;
    public Transform[] floatPoints;
    public Transform Water;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach (Transform t in floatPoints)
        {
            if (t.position.y < Water.position.y) {
                // if point is below water add force to said p
    
                float displacementMultiplyer = Mathf.Clamp01(-t.position.y / depthBeforeSubmerged) 
                    * displacementAmount;

                rb.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(0f, Mathf.Abs(Physics.gravity.y) * 
                displacementMultiplyer, 0f), t.position,ForceMode.Acceleration);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine but the issue is that when I want to add waves to the plane/water the boat begins to float under the water, because shaders will edit the mesh plane but not the the y pose
of the plane/water it will not detect that and think the water is just sitting still with no elevation changes. So what I'm trying to do is get the vertices at the same x and z position as the points and get there y positions. Here's a diagram:

[image: Diagram showing the boat below the waves peaks].

Comment: Questions that are very specific to game development can be asked on stack overflow, but, practically speaking, you may be more to get help on [gamedev.se].  See e.g. [Unity: Water shader vertex offset - how to add mesh collider which updates with vertex offset?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/162419/158277) or [How do you animate/collide against a tessellated mesh?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/168211/158277) or [Advance efficient water physics simulation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66254/158277).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a racyast from the center of the cube straight up and add a force upward depending on the distance of that raycast, so as it gets lower underwater, it'll get forced up more. I dont know if there is any specific way to do it in the basic physics engine.

Comment: this might work but until later, I wont be able to try as the game jam ends on the 29th, and if it doesn't work I might end up losing some work on other aspects of the game.